# Pythonic way of searching for text in binary files

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a binary file with some text on it.
To search for it I'd write, in good old bash:

```
grep -a 'pattern' binaryfile
```

I'd like to achieve the same in Python using the `re` module. The reason is that I want my script to work on multiple platforms.

After reading a bit around I wrote a small `grep` function, and it looks like this:

```
import re
def grep(pattern, binaryfile):
    regexobj = re.compile(pattern)
    for line in binaryfile:
        if regexobj.search(line):
                yield line
```

The code works fine on normal text files.

```
with open('pythoncode.py','r') as f:
    print(list(grep('import', f)))
```

But if I try it on a binary file `with open(binaryfile, 'rb')`, then it throws the following error:

> TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Before I start to dig into all sorts of ad-hoc solutions to my problem... 
Is there a simple Pythonic way to use the `re` module to search for patterns in binary files?

Comment: `open(binary_file_name, 'rb')` to open a binary text file. This has nothing to do with `re`.

Comment: Thanks. That changed the error message to "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object". I'll update the question

Comment: prefix the pattern with `b` like so: `"b'somepattern"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, guys. That did the trick.